# The dual of an optimal problem subject to infinity norm of a matrix

Tags: duality-theorems

The optimal problem comes from paper <[Model selection through sparse maximum likelihood estimation for multivariate Gaussian or binary data>](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1390681.1390696), section 3.1 is 
$$
\hat{y}:= \arg\min_y \{ y^T W^{-1} y: ||y - s ||_{\infty} \leq \lambda \tag{1}
$$
where $y, s \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, $W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\lambda$ is a scalar. $||A||_{\infty}$ denote the maximum abosolute value element in $A$.

Then, section 3.3 given the dual of the above problem is 
$$
\min_x x^T W x - s^T x + \lambda ||x||_1
$$
and withou any computational details. Can someone explaine how this result obatined? or I have done some calculation as follows

1. The new objective function of the optimal problem by Lagrangian method is 
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   \Lambda (y, x) 
   &= y^T W^{-1} y + \sum_i x_i (|y_i - s_i| - \lambda) \\
   &= y^T W^{-1} y + x^T |y-s| - \lambda ||x||_1
   \end{align*}
   $$
2. Let $\hat{y}$ is obtained by $\frac{\partial \Lambda(y, x)}{\partial y} = 0$. 
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   \frac{\partial \Lambda(y, x)}{\partial y} = 2W^{-1}y + \Gamma(y-s) \circ x
   \end{align*}
   $$
   $A \circ B$ denote Hadamard product (element-wise multiply), and
   $$
   {\Gamma(y-s)}_i = \gamma_i = 
   \begin{cases}
   1 \quad & y_i > s_i \\
   -1 \quad & y_i < s_i \\
   -1 < \alpha < 1 \quad & y_i = s_i
   \end{cases}
   $$
   Then $\hat{y} = -\frac{1}{2} W \cdot (\gamma \circ x)$
3. The dual of (1) is 
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   \max_x \min_y \Lambda(y, x) 
   &= \max_x \min_y y^T W^{-1} y + x^T |y-s| - \lambda ||x||_1 \\
   &= \max_x \hat{y}^T W^{-1} \hat{y} + x^T |\hat{y}-s| - \lambda ||x||_1 \\
   &= \frac{1}{4} (\gamma \circ x)^T W (\gamma \circ x) + \frac{1}{2} x^T | W (\gamma \circ x) - s| - \lambda ||x||_1 \\
   \text{(it should be)} &= \min_x x^T W x - s^T x + \lambda ||x||_1
   \end{align*}
   $$

However I cannot get the equivalence of the result of paper and my calculation, what mistakes I have made and how to get the right results? Thanks advance.